# Removing Only Sequential Duplicates from Text FIle?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I've got no problem just blanket removing duplicates - sort -u input.txt > output.txt does that easily. But I want to only remove sequential, subsequent duplicates and I'm not sure how to do that. Here's an example:

Input:

```
One
Two
Two
Three
Four
Five
Five
Six
Seven
Seven
Seven
Three
Three
Two
One
```

Output:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Three
Two
One
```

Has anyone worked out a simple bash sequence to do this, or know of a *NIX command line utility that does?

Edit: clarified the example.

Comment: `awk '!seen[$0]++' file.txt`

Comment: Like ... `uniq input.txt`?

Comment: @Christopher
What does "sequential, subsequent duplicate" mean?

From `One One Two Three One` you want `One Two Three` or `One Two Three One`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I clarified the example to show the intended output. Casaper - the latter.